# brightcove player replace controlbar paly and pause button with play and pause images

Tags: video.js, brightcove

I trying to replace play/pause controlbar icon with images.

```
.video-js .vjs-play-control.vjs-playing .vjs-icon-placeholder:before, .vjs-icon-pause:before {
    background-image: url(pause.png);
}
```

Using above class image get displayed but old icon not remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard icons are fonts not images. You can set `content: none` on the `:before` pseudoeleemnts to remove them and set `background-image` on the elements themselves rather than `:before`.